# Solar System Simulation - Where are my calculations going wrong?

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.6, simulation, physics

I am making a 2D solar system simulation for a project using physical equations, x and y coordinates and a dictionary using 2D lists. I am using a tkinter canvas to construct the animation.

The planet 'earth' seems to disappear of screen with a very slow acceleration at first, then with a huge acceleration not long after. I can't see the problem.

Beforehand, I had only the earth revolving around the Sun, which was successful using the equations in a similar way and moving the earth on the canvas by the x and y components of the the displacement calculated. The dictionary is order by `{(-body):[[x, y], [x velocity, y velocity], mass, [change in x displacement, change in y displacement]}`. The values calculated are stored or added to some values in this dictionary if necessary. Here's the code I'm using:

```
G = 6.67384 * 10 ** -11                                              
scale = 10 ** 13                                                                             
speed = 1                 
global user_status
screen = Tk()
screen.title('Solar System' + ' - ' + user_status)
screen.geometry('1300x700')

ani = Canvas(screen, width=1300, height=700)
ani.pack()
ani.create_rectangle(0, 0, 1300, 700, fill='Black')

sunx = 636
suny = 343
sun = ani.create_oval(sunx-10, suny-10, sunx+10, suny+10, fill='yellow')

earthx = 746
earthy = 343

moonx = 747
moony = 343

bodies = {'sun':  [[sunx, suny],     [0, 0],                         1.989 * 10 ** 30 * speed / scale,      [0, 0]],
          'earth':[[earthx, earthy], [0, 347.3833062 * 1.033447099], 5.972 * 10 ** 24 * speed / scale,      [0, 0]],
          'moon': [[moonx, moony],   [0, 360],                       7.34767309 * 10 ** 22 * speed / scale, [0, 0]]
          }

body_names = []
for Ω in bodies.keys():
    body_names.append(Ω)

moon = ani.create_oval(moonx - 4, moony - 4, moonx + 4, moony + 4, fill='grey70')
earth = ani.create_oval(earthx-6, earthy-6, earthx+6, earthy+6, fill='sky blue')

timestep = 0.0001

while True:
    for i in range(len(body_names)):
        body1 = body_names[i]
        x1 = bodies[body1][0][0]
        y1 = bodies[body1][0][1]
        total_Fx = 0
        total_Fy = 0
        body1_mass = bodies[body1][2]
        for j in range(len(body_names)):
            body2 = body_names[j]
            if body1 != body2:
                x2 = bodies[body2][0][0]
                y2 = bodies[body2][0][1]
                body2_mass = bodies[body2][2]

                r = sqrt(((x1 - x2) ** 2) + ((y1 - y2) ** 2))
                rx = (x1 - x2)
                angle = (acos(rx/r))

                F = (G * body1_mass * body2_mass) / (r ** 2)
                Fx = F * cos(angle)
                Fy = F * sin(angle)

                total_Fx += Fx
                total_Fy += Fy

        ax = (total_Fx / body1_mass)
        ay = (total_Fy / body1_mass)

        ux = bodies[body1][1][0]
        uy = bodies[body1][1][1]

        vx = ux - (ax * timestep)
        if x1 <= sunx:
            vy = uy + (ay * timestep)
        else:
            vy = uy - (ay * timestep)

        sx = vx * timestep * speed
        sy = vy * timestep * speed

        bodies[body1][3][0] = sx
        bodies[body1][3][1] = sy

        bodies[body1][1][0] += vx
        bodies[body1][1][1] += vy

        bodies[body1][0][0] = x1 + sx
        bodies[body1][0][1] = y1 + sy
        print(bodies[body1][1], body1)

    move_e_x = bodies['earth'][3][0]
    move_e_y = bodies['earth'][3][1]
    ani.move(earth, move_e_x, move_e_y)

    move_m_x = bodies['moon'][3][0]
    move_m_y = bodies['moon'][3][1]
    ani.move(moon, move_m_x, move_m_y)

    ani.update()
```

I want the objects to simultaneously orbit the sun and each other, but I get this error message after the bodies have gone far off the screen:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/apple/Documents/School/Computer Science/NEA/NEA Programming/Solar System Simulator.py", line 380, in <module>
    simulate()                                                                               # Calls the 'simulate' function
  File "/Users/apple/Documents/School/Computer Science/NEA/NEA Programming/Solar System Simulator.py", line 290, in simulate
    r = sqrt(((x1 - x2) ** 2) + ((y1 - y2) ** 2))
OverflowError: (34, 'Result too large')
```

I know this may not be a very efficient piece of code, but all I need is some help on how to do it this way. The problem seems to occur in the displacement or velocity calculations. Any ideas?

Comment: The numbers are getting too large. Try scaling them down.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but I have successfully managed to create an orbiting affect using these numbers, but without the dictionary storage system, so I don't think the numbers need scaling, but I don't know why the numbers get so large. It seems to occur in the velocity or displacement calculations.

Comment: Then you need to do some debugging to find out at what point the calculations are off.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not finding this advice particularly helpful. I don't know why at all or where the values are becoming so large, it seems to be unexplained.

Comment: I can reproduce the problem on Windows using Python 3.7.3—so there something fundamentally wrong with your code. The `OverflowError` occurs doing the computations for the sun and earth. I'm not sure how your animation works and what all the values are in your dictionary, but it seems strange that values printed for the sun seem to change each iteration—shouldn't the sun be stationary? Also since you're updating values in the dictionary, could it possibly be an accumulated mathematical error since float-point math on a computer is only approximate, especially with large numbers.

Comment: The calculations for the sun are not used to move it, so they are essentially ignored. The dictionary layout is described above the code, if you can understand it (please tell me if you can't!). Thanks for your help, though!

Comment: start by figuring out which number is too huge -- either `(x1-x2)**2` or `(y1-y2)**2`. Then figure out if `x1`, `y1`, `x2`, and `y2` are what you expect them to be. Work back up through the code to see how they are calculated. In other words, step through the code by hand and do the calculations yourself. At some point the numbers deviate from what you expect.

Comment: Bryan Oakley - Thanks for your help! I'll try to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The initial velocity is getting received twice: in each loop, the initial velocity is called and used, so itself and the new velocity are added together, causing it to more than double each time.

The new added velocity is now calculated and then only added once to the initial velocity. The planets now orbit. There are currently 9 bodies orbiting the Sun.